# Unable to get the text from a javascript offer with selenium (it doesn't show inside inspect web elements)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm grateful to you just for coming here. I'll try to make the clearest explanation I can.

I'm extracting the offers from a supermarket website with selenium and I found that some offers are not shown inside the inspect web elements option, so I don't know how to get them.

[Link to page 7 of the supermarket](https://www.online.bmsupermercados.es/es/c/ofertas/99999?orderById=5&page=7)

If you access the link with your browser, a list of products will appear and when you mouseover the yellow BM symbol at the first item, "AHORRAS 7%" (you save 7%, promotin article) shows up. This one is the one not appearing inside inspect elements. Instead, the second one "AHORRAS 10%" does, as on previous pages. In this page there are several items coded like that.

The complete code to reproduce the extraction is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#Link
html1='https://www.online.bmsupermercados.es/es/c/ofertas/99999?orderById=5&page=7'

#Get html
def get_sel_response(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(html1)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "paginator-input")))
        html = driver.page_source
    finally:
        driver.quit()
        return html
#Get price
def get_html(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    return soup
#Get content
def get_content(soup,tag,clase): 
    data = [element.getText(strip=True)+'\n' for element in soup.find_all(tag, {"class": clase})]
    text=''.join(data)
    return text

##Reset offers
offers=''
text3=''
#Reset the number of BM membership offers when starts a new page
k=0

#Main block
html=get_sel_response(html1)
soup=get_html(html)
for j in range(1,21,1):
    #Offers
    tag3='div'
    clase3='product-detail__pictos--offer ng-star-inserted'
    text3=get_content(soup,tag3,clase3).split('\n')[j-1]
    #If offer from BM membership
    if len(text3)==0:
        clase3='panel--check panel--check__deferred u-width--50 ng-star-inserted'
        text3=get_content(soup,tag3,clase3).split('\n')[k]
        k=k+1
    offers='\n'.join([offers,text3])
print(offers)
```

It happens in page 7 (first item, as mentioned), and also it happens on the last item of page 6. If you want to check the code, you can run it for pages 1 to 5 and you'll see the 20 elements' offers are extracted.

I'm trying to search for a solution (saw some questions regarding javascript appending new divs after hovering, but it doesn't seem like it's that). I'm noob enough not to know yet how to find something that seems to not be there in the code.

Any help, suggestion or recommendation of how to extract that specific text ("AHORRAS 7%" or just "7%") from somewhere will be deeply appreciated.

UPDATE: as of today, it happens in page 6, product 17th and 18th. My script withouth offers run in 10mins, with the idea provided it takes 1h+ to read everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for. However, I hope you will get a good idea how to capture the text from a `tool tip` which is only visible when you mouse hover.

The below code will 1. Launch URL(page7) 2. Store all the `div` elements of offer 3. mouse-hover each one of the offers 4. Capture the `tool tip` and save it into an array.

**Code with in-line explanation:**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# Below method will mouse hover on the desired element
def scroll_to_element(driver, element_locator):
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    try:
        actions.move_to_element(element_locator).perform()
    except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException as e:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element_locator)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.online.bmsupermercados.es/es/c/ofertas/99999?orderById=5&page=7")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Below line of code will click on Accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Aceptar todo']"))).click()
# Below line will store all the <div> elements on which the mouse-hover will be done
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pictos ng-star-inserted']")))
offers = []

# Iterate through each element, mouse hover and capture the tool tip
for element in elements:
    scroll_to_element(driver, element)
    toolTip = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel--offer pictos ng-star-inserted']")))
    offers.append(toolTip.text.splitlines()[1])
    time.sleep(1)

print(offers)
```

**Console result:**

```
['AHORRAS 7%', 'AHORRAS 10%', 'OFERTA', '70% DESCUENTO EN LA 2ª UNIDAD', 'OFERTA', 'OFERTA', '50% DESCUENTO EN LA 2ª UNIDAD', 'AHORRAS 30%', 'AHORRAS 10%', 'AHORRAS 10%', 'AHORRAS 10%', '50% DESCUENTO EN LA 2ª UNIDAD', '50% DESCUENTO EN LA 2ª UNIDAD', 'AHORRAS 10%', 'AHORRAS 0,30€', 'AHORRAS 0,30€', 'AHORRAS 10%', 'AHORRAS 10%', 'AHORRAS 10%', 'AHORRAS 0,20€']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shawn, as you say, not the exact answer I'm looking for, however, it helps me a lot since it gets the whole information from the offers. Implementing this option in my code, sometimes it stops hovering when the BM Support button pops up. I will study this option further.

Comment: I consider it not answered yet because this solution doesn't successfully run because the BM Support Help Desk mess with it. But don't worry, I will keept track of the question and if no better answer is provided, I will accept your answer. Count on it.